# Visual studio 2017 cross platform library linking

Tags: raspberry-pi, visual-studio-2017, cross-platform

I am trying to compile some code using visual studios cross platform feature, but I am having some issues, I copied over the include files like they say you should and intellisense works fine. during compiling at the linking stage I get the can not find lib...

```
Linking objects
1>  Invoking ld
1>  g++ -o "/home/pi/projects/PiLedTestSetup/bin/ARM/Debug/PiLedTestSetup.out" -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack /home/pi/projects/PiLedTestSetup/obj/ARM/Debug/camera.o /home/pi/projects/PiLedTestSetup/obj/ARM/Debug/cameracontrol.o /home/pi/projects/PiLedTestSetup/obj/ARM/Debug/main.o /home/pi/projects/PiLedTestSetup/obj/ARM/Debug/Serial.o -lwiringPi -llibmmal_core -llibmmal_util -llibmmal_vc_client -llibvcos -llibbcm_host -llibbrcmGLESv2 -llibbrcmEGL.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmmal_core
1>  /usr/bin//usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmmal_core
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmmal_util
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmmal_vc_client
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibvcos
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibbcm_host
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibbrcmGLESv2
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibbrcmEGL.so
1>  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

using the make file I originally used(compiling with make on the pi works fine!) it links to the lib folder like this link_directories(/opt/vc/lib) so in vs I added that just like the include Directories in VC++ Directories->Library directory
[image]

so I was wondering am I missing something? How do you all add you libraries.

Edit:
so I found out how to add the lib folder, go to properties-general-additional library directory

so now it gives the -L (-L/opt/vc/lib) parameter in the build string or what you call it but its still not finding it. I even tried with file extension but that does not help ether

```
1>Target Link:
1>  Linking objects
1>  Invoking ld
1>  g++ -o "/home/pi/projects/PiLedTestSetup/bin/ARM/Debug/PiLedTestSetup.out" -Wl,--stats -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-L/opt/vc/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack /home/pi/projects/PiLedTestSetup/obj/ARM/Debug/camera.o /home/pi/projects/PiLedTestSetup/obj/ARM/Debug/cameracontrol.o /home/pi/projects/PiLedTestSetup/obj/ARM/Debug/main.o /home/pi/projects/PiLedTestSetup/obj/ARM/Debug/Serial.o -lwiringPi -llibmmal_core.so -llibmmal_util.so -llibmmal_vc_client.so -llibvcos.so -llibbcm_host.so -llibbrcmGLESv2.so -llibbrcmEGL.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmmal_core.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmmal_core.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmmal_util.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmmal_vc_client.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibvcos.so
1>  /usr/bincannot find -llibmmal_util.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmmal_vc_client.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibvcos.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibbcm_host.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibbrcmGLESv2.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibbrcmEGL.so
1>  /ld: cannot find -llibbcm_host.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibbrcmGLESv2.so
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibbrcmEGL.so
1>  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The make file on the pi has this and it compile and links no problem. am I missing something ?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( picamdemo )
SET(COMPILE_DEFINITIONS -Werror)
include_directories(/opt/vc/include)
link_directories(/opt/vc/lib)
add_executable(picamdemo picam.cpp camera.cpp cameracontrol.cpp graphics.cpp)

target_link_libraries(picamdemo libmmal_core.so libmmal_util.so libmmal_vc_client.so libvcos.so libbcm_host.so libbrcmGLESv2.so libbrcmEGL.so)
```

Comment: it seems not to complain about the `-lwiringPi` - why? usually the lib is also omitted, give e.g.  `-lmmal_core -lmmal_util` a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I asked this question also on the Microsoft forums and got an answer.

"Using '-l' switch, would omit file-extension and prefix 'lib':
E.g. if name of library is 'libmmal_core.so', then

```
 -lmmal_core
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a43c9f43-eb8c-4af1-9615-49fd58e2de92/visual-studio-2017-cross-platform-library-linking?forum=vcgeneral